# Explanation of unexpectedly large offset of the first occurrence of five consecutive zeroes in the sequence of second-to-last bits of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Assuming that $x$ is a real number, the function $f_n(x)$ is defined as follows: the value of $f_n(x)$ is equal to the number of bits before the first occurrence of $n$ consecutive zero bits in the binary representation of the fractional part of $x$. For example, $$\begin{array}{l}
f_1(0.11100110001\ldots) = f_2(0.11100110001\ldots) = 3,\\
f_2(0.1110110001\ldots) = f_3(0.11100110001\ldots) = 6.
\end{array}$$

Here we can assume that if $n$ consecutive zero bits never occur in $x$, the value of $f_n(x)$ is undefined: for example, $f_n(\frac{1}{3}) = f_n(0.010101\ldots_2)$ is undefined for any $n>1$.

Let $r$ denote the real number such that $0 < r < 1$ and an $i$-th bit of the binary representation of the fractional part of $r$ is equal to the second-to-last bit of the binary representation of an $i$-th prime. That is, $$r = 0.11011001101001101011011000110\ldots_2$$

There are $131007$ zero bits in the first $262144 = 2^{18}$ bits of the binary representation of the fractional part of $r$. The number of zeroes in the first $500000$ bits is $249888$.

Consider the value of $f_5(r)=377$, which is significantly larger than expected in an unbiased sequence of random (or pseudo-random) bits: for comparison, $$f_5(\pi)=95, f_5(e)=89, f_5(\sqrt{2})=7, f_5(\sqrt{3})=92, f_5(\sqrt{5})=53, f_5(\sqrt{6})=25, f_5(\sqrt{7})=115, f_5(\sqrt{8})=6, f_5(\sqrt{10})=16.$$

Question: why is the value of $f_5(r)$ so large?

Comment: In other words, you are asking about the first time that $5$ consecutive primes are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: I suspect this is related to the issue with the last decimal digits of consecutive primes having an "anti-sameness" bias, e.g., as described in arXiv's [Unexpected biases in the distribution of consecutive primes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720), the Scientific American article [Peculiar Pattern Found in "Random" Prime Numbers](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/peculiar-pattern-found-in-random-prime-numbers/), the Phys.org article [Mathematician pair find prime numbers aren't as random as thought](https://phys.org/news/2016-03-mathematician-pair-prime-random-thought.html), etc.

Comment: @ZachTeitler: yes. And why is this much later than the first time that 5 consecutive primes are congruent to $3$ modulo $4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is particularly surprising.  In particular, it seems like it's a 1-in-400 event or so.  Mathematics is big enough that there are [lots of rare events](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Guy697-712.pdf)!

Let's first think about the simpler question of asking when we expect to first see a sequence of five zeroes in a sequence of Bernoulli ($p = 1/2$) random variates.  You might expect that this random variate - the one counting the first sequence position at which we see five zeroes; let's call it $S$ - satisfies $S \thicksim \mathrm{Geometric}(1/32)$, in which case $\Pr(S \ge 377) \approx 6 \times 10^{-6}$ - a very unlikely event indeed.

This belief, however, is false!  The key point is that appearances of five zeroes are very not independent, and this lack of independence makes the tails for our sequence behave very differently.  Here are two heuristic explanations for this lack of independence:

- **Disjoint runs of zeroes repel one another.**  This is just because runs of zeroes have to be separated by ones.
- **Long runs of zeroes cluster.**  If I know that there is a run of five zeroes starting at position $i$, then the probability that there is a run of five zeroes starting at position $i+1$ is $1/2$ - far greater than the $1/32$ expected by chance.

A nice rule-of-thumb for runs in this particular process is that $S$ is approximately distributed like $2\cdot\mathrm{Geometric(1/32)}$.  I think the expected value of $S$ is actually 62; in general, the expected waiting time before $n$ zeroes is $2^{n+1}-2$.  It's clear that the distribution should be geometric in the large scale, because the effects described above are short-range - in other words, the distribution of $S$ is memoryless at large scales.  The constant $2$ is somewhat harder to explain easily; maybe somebody will provide a good explanation in the comments.

Assuming we buy this rule-of-thumb, then, we can compute $$\Pr(S \ge 377 | S \sim 2\mathrm{Geometric}(1/32)) \approx 2.5 \times 10^{-3} \approx \sqrt{6 \times 10^{-6}}$$ so that what you observed is a 1-in-400 event.  This does not include possible contributions from phenomena like those described in John Omielan's comment.

You can look at Feller for more detailed analysis of runs like this; it's a classic topic in probability theory.  A nice martingale-based approach to lots of similar questions, including surprising phenomena like the nontransitive [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game) (featured in a great Martin Gardner column!) and Conway's algorithm for analyzing this game, is found in [Li (1980)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2243018).

Comment: [1/2]: I was not implying that an event like this is particularly rare, but I am not sure that it is a 1-in-400 event. It seems that it is somewhere close to a 1-in-$(k\times400)$ event, where $1.3 < k < 1.8$. For all possible strings of size $5$ (where each char belongs to a standard Latin alphabet of size $26$), I computed the corresponding $512$-bit value of [SHA3-512 hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3), which is as unbiased as it is practically possible.

Comment: [2/2]: There are exactly $17980$ five-letter strings $\{s_0, \ldots, s_{17979}\}$ such that the value of $f_5(\text{SHA3-512}(s_i))$ is either greater than $376$ or undefined (which means that the corresponding hash does not contain five consecutive zeroes.) Note that $26^5/17980 \approx 661$, which is greater than $400$. But in case of $r$, the sequence of bits is _not_ unbiased, so I am still not sure what property of primes causes the late occurrence of five consecutive zeroes.

Comment: The difference between your 1-in-660 heuristic and my 1-in-400 heuristic (note the use of "approximately distributed") is merely a constant term adjustment to the distribution of $S$ (somewhere around 15, maybe).  I'm not familiar enough to know if this is well-understood; there's a decent chance it's in Feller anyways.

I don't understand the reasoning behind your use of SHA3; there are better PRNGs to use for something like this than what you did.  But this is a small quibble and should not affect your result very much.

Comment: I don't know that there's a good explanation for this occurrence other than "that's what the primes are".  I think you might be privileging the hypothesis (https://wiki.lesswrong.com/wiki/Privileging_the_hypothesis).  Sure, this outcome is weird, but there are a lot of tests you could have run and some tests (one out of every 660 or so) should have a 1-in-660 outcome.  Maybe you're just not paying much attention to the other tests you ran because their outcomes were not so unlikely.

Comment: > "I think you might be privileging the hypothesis" < I am not sure what hypothesis you are implying.